# Where can I find all the data from MATLAB's Mapping Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, mapping, libraries

So for example,

```
ax = worldmap('World');
setm(ax, 'Origin', [0 180 0])
land = shaperead('landareas', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(ax, land, 'FaceColor', [0.5 0.7 0.5])
lakes = shaperead('worldlakes', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(lakes, 'FaceColor', 'blue')
rivers = shaperead('worldrivers', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(rivers, 'Color', 'blue')
```

This creates a world map with a landmasses and bodies of water colored in one some map projection of the earth.

Where do I find all the geographic data labels used by shaperead? The 'worldrivers', 'worldlakes', 'landareas'?

There must be a library with all of these things somewhere right? Or a local file? I have been trying to find it but the documentation is less than helpful. I would like to know what other features I can draw!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the built-in shape files in `toolbox/map/mapdata` (relative to the matlab installation directory). In 2016b these are

```
concord_hydro_line.shp
concord_roads.shp
worldrivers.shp
landareas.shp
usastatelo.shp
boston_placenames.shp
usastatehi.shp
boston_roads.shp
tsunamis.shp
worldlakes.shp
worldcities.shp
concord_hydro_area.shp
```